# JQuery Autocomplete working in Chrome but not in android using phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, google-chrome, cordova

I have write simple code for Auto-complete for search.
I am developing android application using PhoneGap. I have write code for Auto-complete for search and it's working perfectly but when i am going to run in android its not working.

[Here is the sample code](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

I am using same file not a single change.Google Chrome is allow to test HTML 5 database pages so first i am always test it in browser and then copy that all files into device.

[Here is my code](http://jsfiddle.net/cjn38/1/)

I have add my dynamic function which return array from database and that is also working in Google Chrome and i can see the perfect result as per the database.

When i run the code in device i always get below error :

```
TypeError: Result of expression '$( "#pur_cat_text" ).autocomplete' [undefined] is not a function.
```

I don't know where is the issue and how to solve it.
Please guild be how can i solve this.

Thanks for read query.

Comment: Seems like there is a function missing: Get_All_Category is not defined  (in google's chrome console)

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet thanks for reply but i haven't write that function in fiddle but yet that will shows static output in drop down

Comment: Well, In order to be able to help (and debug this script) you i would like to see the full code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ohh after spent almost half day finally i found the exact solution.

Issue was in Live Script URL.

In sample code they have set live script URL and i haven't save it at locally.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

So may be in mobile that all js & css haven't loading so due to that reason they are not able to find

`'$( "#pur_cat_text" ).autocomplete'` and giving me error.

At finally i have save both JS & CSS at locally and now i am able to run my code